# Split String into an array of String

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string

I'm trying to find a way to split a String into an array of String(s), and I need to split it whenever a white spice is encountered, example

> "hi i'm paul"

into"

> "hi" "i'm" "paul"

How do you represent white spaces in split() method using RegularExpression?

Comment: why do you even need regular expression for that? couldn't you just do `String[] myList = myString.split(" ");`

Comment: There is a tool called Visual REGEXP (http://laurent.riesterer.free.fr/regexp/) it can help you visualise the result of you regexp (perl regexp that is, but more or less all lang is using perl regexp so that is not a problem)

Comment: "i dont know that much yet about RegExp" - sounds like you need to remedy that, because asking someone else to write your regexes for you is not sustainable.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need a regular expression like `"\\s+"`, which means: *split whenever at least one whitespace is encountered*. The full Java code is:

```
try {
    String[] splitArray = input.split("\\s+");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // 
}
```

Comment: @Gabe: I don't think so. He wants anything, except whitespeces. For example he wants the apostrophe in "i'm" to be kept together with the i and the m.

Comment: Oops, I meant `\s+`! (as you have it now)

Answer (score 7):

`String[] result = "hi i'm paul".split("\\s+");` to split across one or more cases.

Or you could take a look at Apache Common StringUtils. It has `StringUtils.split(String str)` method that splits string using white space as delimiter. It also has other useful utility methods